# Criar mascara de Telefone para EditText

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mask

Eu estou tentando criar uma mascara para o meu campo telefone, vi alguns fóruns e tentei o código abaixo, mas ele esta colocando um outro padrão... estou precisando colocar no padrao br.

```
EditText inputField = (EditText) FindViewById(Resource.Id.editMensagemTelefone);
inputField.AddTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir da API 21 foi adicionado um [construtor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html#PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(java.lang.String)) que recebe uma string contendo um código de país que será utilizado pelo `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher`.

O [construtor sem paramêtros](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java#L59) invoca `Locale.getDefault().getCountry()` para obter qual código de país usar para o formatador.

Considere também utilizar a maneira mais idiomática do Xamarin para obter a sua View, que é utilizar o método genérico `FindViewById`. O resultado seria esse:

```
var inputField = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editMensagemTelefone);
inputField.AddTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("BR"));
```